# Bash Perform multiple grep searches using patterns stored in a file

Tags: bash, unix, search

Working in the default Unix environment that comes with Mac computers. Environment contains the following:

- 1 file that is a list of ~250 words I want to use as search patterns
- 10 or so .tsv files to search individually using each of these search patterns
- 1 file to append with the search results

I want to run the following script:

```
for file in *.tsv; 
do 
echo "Processing $file"; 
grep -n PATTERN $file | cut -f 1,2,3 >> Results_File.lst; 
done
```

But I do not know how to run the script repeatedly for multiple patterns stored in a separate file.

Here is a small slice of the patterns file:

```
    AXDND1
    BAZ2B
    BBS10
    BRIP1
    etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `for` loop. You can pass the `*.tsv` glob to `grep` and it will search in all of those files. If you pass the option `-f pattern.txt` to `grep` it will search for all patterns in `pattern.txt`.

The following command should do the whole work:

```
grep -n -f pattern.txt *.tsv | cut -f 1,2,3 >> Results_File.lst
```

Check [`man grep`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep) for further explanation of `grep` and it's options.